# TracingKafkaClientSupplier error "Implementations of KafkaClientSupplier should implement the getAdmin() method"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm upgrading a Spring Boot application to Boot 2.6.1, Cloud 2021.0.0 and Cloud Stream 3.2.1.

This application has a bunch of KStreams such as:

```
    @Bean
    fun processEvent() =
        Function<KStream<ID, EventReceived>, KStream<Id, UpdatedInfo?>> { events ->
            ...
        }
```

Now the application crashes on startup:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Implementations of KafkaClientSupplier should implement the getAdmin() method.
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.java:107)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Implementations of KafkaClientSupplier should implement the getAdmin() method.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaClientSupplier.getAdmin(KafkaClientSupplier.java:40)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:846)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:711)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:337)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

What could be the problem here?

**UPDATE**

I found that the problematic clientSupplier is `brave.kafka.streams.TracingKafkaClientSupplier`:

[image]

This class doesn't implement the expected method from `KafkaClientSupplier` (kafka-streams 3.0.0):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open an issue against Brave - or perhaps there's a newer version that's compatible with the 3.0.0 Kafka jars.

In the meantime, you should be able to downgrade the kafka-clients and kafka-streams to 2.8.1.

If you are using the embedded kafka broker for testing, you will need to downgrade some other jars too. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.1-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: Yep, it doesn't seem to be compatible with kafka-streams 3.0.0. I already opened an issue: https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/1316